# NameError: global name 'codepoint2name' is not defined

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I am using Python 2.7.3 on Windows XP
I am using Pyscripter 2.5.3.0

I am trying to get beautiful soup running and using the following test code

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.google.com")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
print soup.prettify()
```

The code stops in `dammit.py`. The error is:

```
Message File Name   Line    Position    
Traceback               
    <module>    D:\Python\TestBS.py 19      
    <module>    C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\bs4\__init__.py   29      
    <module>    C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\bs4\builder\__init__.py   4       
    <module>    C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py    5       
    <module>    C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\bs4\dammit.py 49      
    EntitySubstitution  C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\bs4\dammit.py 70      
    _populate_class_variables   C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\bs4\dammit.py 57      
NameError: global name 'codepoint2name' is not defined
```

on this part of the code

```
class EntitySubstitution(object):

    """Substitute XML or HTML entities for the corresponding characters."""

    def _populate_class_variables():
        lookup = {}
        reverse_lookup = {}
        characters_for_re = []
        for codepoint, name in list(codepoint2name.items()):
```

Comment: What version of BeautifulSoup?

Comment: @Blender: from the code sample and traceback it seems to be version 4 (`bs4`).

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in BeautifulSoup. Clearly the author missed to import the symbol from the 'htmlentitydefs' module. So you can either fix this yourself by adding the import to the
BeautifulSoup code. In addition: contact the BeautifulSoup author or file a bug report.

Comment: If I putfrom htmlentitydefs import codepoint2name
print codepoint2name.items()